# How to debug or analyze Kubernetes RBAC rule verbs and Api Groups

Tags: kubernetes

How can I debug all `Rules` with their `Verbs` and `ApiGroups` for a kubernetes `ServiceAccount`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`kubectl` supports testing the RBAC rights for a particular Service Account with the `auth can-i` sub-command. The syntax looks as follows:

```
kubectl auth can-i -n --as system:serviceaccount:<namespace>:<serviceaccount> <verb> <resource>
```

For example:

```
kubectl auth can-i --as system:serviceaccount:default:my-serviceaccount create deployments
```

More information can be found [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authorization/#checking-api-access).

Comment: That's helpful! Just one question: Is it possible to specify the api group in this command?

Comment: Don't think so, but isn't the api group implicitly provided, when you specify the resource, e.g. if you do a `kubectl auth can-i create deployments`, this implies you have rights on  apps/v1

Comment: You're right: The api group is implicitly provided. This works:
kubectl auth can-i --as system:serviceaccount:monitor:monitor-kube-prometheus-st-operator get prometheusrules

Answer (score 3):

***k9s*** offer some nice views for this task:

**1. Find Role Bindings**

First you have to find the ClusterRoleBindings or RoleBindings for a ServiceAccount:

- Type `:` and `clusterrolebindings` or `rolebindings`
- Search for your ServiceAccount by `/` and name of ServiceAccount (e.g. `monitor-kube-prometheus-st-operator`)
- Now *k9s* lists all `(Cluster)RoleBindings`
  [image]

**2. Display Role Bindings**

- Open `(Cluster)RoleBindings`
- All given and forbidden rules are displayed:
  [image]